# Реализация Двусвязного списка через массив на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, список, динамические-массивы

в общем была поставлена такая задача: Разработать программу, которая запрашивает N целых чисел у пользователя (N от 1 до 256), ни одно из которых, не повторяется.
 И выводит на экран 1).количество элементов, 2).среднее арифметическое,
3).минимальный и макс. элементы, 4)четвёртый эл. последовательности, 5)эл., который идёт перед минимальным.

И всё бы ничего, если бы всё это нужно было реализовать через массив, но нужно реализовать через двусвязный список в виде одномерного массива (то есть один элемент занимает три ячейки массива 1.ключ(значение), 2.указатель на пред. ключ, 3.указатель на след. ключ).

Я, в принципе, хорошо понимаю что такое двусвязный список в теории, но как реализовать на практике ума не приложу.

Буду благодарен за советы!

Comment: Вместо указателей на следющий и предыдущий элементы списка (стандартная реализация списка) используйте *индексы* элементов одномерного массива, в которых будете размещать элементы списка.

Comment: Интересно, кто же тут старательно минусует и рекомендует закрыть вопрос, в котором совершенно четко написано, что именно человек нее понимает?